# MySQL database uses too much CPU

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, database-tuning

I have a MySQL database which uses too much CPU. I am actually performing benchmarking to the web servers which queries the database. Right now the database is being the bottleneck, it uses too much CPU. The VM has 5 vCPU and 4GB of memory.

Is there any changes I can do so it uses less CPU?  And increase the performance?

```
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size= 1000000000

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

Output from `MySQLTuner`:

```
[OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 695M (Tables: 8)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 8

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] User 'user@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[--] There are 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations  ---------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 45m 29s (1M q [560.371 qps], 1K conn, TX: 434M, RX: 73M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 1017.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.4G (38.57% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.4G (38.50% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (2K/1M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (152/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.07%  (1/1442)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 7.8% (105K cached / 1M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 39159937
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 37K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 6782
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (54 on disk / 37K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 59% (581 created / 1K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 4% (25 open / 515 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (0/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1M immediate / 1M locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/98.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 3.9% (128 cached / 123 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 953.0M/695.3M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[OK] InnoDB Used buffer: 97.41% (59413 used/ 60992 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (248726755 hits/ 248733105 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 99.83% (1724316 hits/ 1727328 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 3012 writes)

-------- ThreadPool Metrics --------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- AriaDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 400)
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 151)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
```

`vmstat` output:

```
root@database:/home/user# vmstat 1 10
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
11  0      0 1264444 156800 1595928    0    0     1    39   33   26  2  2 39  1
14  0      0 1263652 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 15953 11988 87  7  5  0
 9  0      0 1263584 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 20043 10770 86  8  5  0
18  0      0 1263696 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 13679 10370 88  6  6  0
11  0      0 1263728 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 12920 9972 89  6  5  0
13  0      0 1263696 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 13454 10560 88  6  6  0
11  0      0 1263544 156800 1595928    0    0     0    20 14192 10877 88  6  6  0
12  0      0 1263556 156800 1595928    0    0     0    88 13901 10417 88  6  5  0
16  0      0 1263428 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 12457 10490 88  6  6  0
 8  0      0 1263468 156800 1595928    0    0     0    16 12470 10216 89  5  5  0
```

As you can see the database has high CPU footprint, while the web server is not observing any high usage.
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify too much CPU? Is it in Sys, User, IOWait? Your database seems tiny so everything should come from memory. I see highest connection usage is 100%. What type of benchmark are you doing? Do you see issues with real world usage too or only in the benchmarks?

Comment: Since I have allocated 5 vcpu's. I am observing the VM to use usage of CPU up to 500 % and the mysql process is the reason. My database is not more than 300 - 400 MB in size. Im using Autobench on the web server (which uses httperf under the hood). Is there any changes I can do to reduce the CPU footprint ?

Comment: Can you run `vmstat 1 10` when you see this behaviour and update the question with the output? Databases are usually more IO bound than CPU. High CPU usage is usually caused by some lock contention. At this point this can be many things. Take a look at innodb semaphores and mutexes.

Comment: See updated post @KárolyNagy

Comment: Check the processlist when the cpu utilization is high (`show processlist;`). Disable query cache, enable slow log, [analyze](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) slow log, optimize slow queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do show full processlist, and then you could see if there are some long running queries, if yes you need to optimize indexes (see explain and add index on the fields JOINs are using).

You need to increase query cache size, it's ridiculously low (and limit is ridiculously high)...

query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 128M

or even try to make it

query_cache_limit       = 384K
query_cache_size        = 512M

There's no mutex/contention issues, if you had it then CPU would be underutilized.

If there are no long running queries and setting qcache won't help, that'd probably mean that you need to look around for normal server, could be that these vcpus are slow, but most likely indexes are not there and cache is too low.

Comment: That actually worked. My CPU is stable and stays around 30 % now. WOW! Thanks. Miracle

Comment: Beware!  The read-only benchmark benefited; what about real life?

Comment: @RickJames if you looked at the statistics you'd discover that there is extremely high number of reads and almost no writes, and very high number of cache prunes which indicates that cache size is too small.

If mysql cache would be always bad, then probably it'd be removed from the server altogether. Dogmas are bad, when optimizing and turning cache on is in many cases best thing you can do - for read only traffic.

Comment: @Slawek too many prunes  and low efficiency most probably means the queries are not cacheable - for example queries which contain current datetime as one of the (application added) parameters will be cached, but can only be ever used for the one specific second, then they will just sit in the cache, taking space, unless they are purged by table update or pruned after all space is taken by them.

Comment: That would be a good point but the variable's name is Qcache_lowmem_prunes... it counts prunes related to low memory, not cache invalidations, which you can get by doing :

Qcache_inserts - Qcache_queries_in_cache

BTW: Queries that contain NOW(), CURTIME(), etc. are not cachable... they'll not land in cache...

Comment: @Slawek - You have good points about the QC.  But I think the OP is doing a read-only benchmark, and failing to include the writes that he will see in real life.  And the benchmark _may_ be unrealistically repeating the ids, etc, in the test.  It would be nice if he would weigh in on this discussion.

Comment: @Slawek `or pruned after all space is taken by them` - and I specifically mean queries which do not use `NOW()` in SQL but instead get the datetime/timestamp supplied by the application - these *look* cacheable but they are not, because they will never be repeated in any other second.

Answer (score 5):

Your CPU is spending most of the time in user space. That is most likely due to locking issues or very inefficient queries.

What I would do is go through the following steps and check after each if the problem is still present. Proceed only if it is.

1. Disable query_cache: you don't get too much benefit from it anyway and it's a common contention point.
2. Turn on slow query log with `log_queries_not_using_indexes` analyse your queries and fix your unindexed joins. From your mysqltuner output: `[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 6782` [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) can be a great help in that.
3. Look at the mutexes

   a.) Check the output of `show engine innodb mutex;`

   b.) If you have performance_schema and mutex_instances table check `select * from performance_schema.mutex_instances;`. If not I strongly recommend to set it up.

   Maybe your queries lock up each other. And simply semaphore spins use up the cpu time. Fix any obvious queries showing up as a possible "intruder". You can look for select for updates, insert .. on duplicate key update .. queries which are very common cause of this behaviour.
4. `perf top -p [mysql process id]` can give you more information where mysql spends most of the CPU time in. If you get to this point you can form a much more specific question about how to overcome that certain problem.

Answer (score 2):

High CPU means poorly tuned queries, lack of adequate indexes (esp. composite), and/or bogus benchmark.

Your benchmarking is read-only, so raising the QC may benefit *only* the benchmark.  Don't raise it!  Instead, turn off the Query cache.  Otherwise, when writes come in, you will suffer.  The bigger the QC is, the longer it takes to purge.  And meanwhile, the `SELECT` is sitting there waiting for a *global* mutex.

Ignore "fragmented tables"; it is bogus.

If you have 152 simultaneous users connected, they are probably stumbling over each other.  The system *might* run better with a lower limit.  And the latency for each will probably improve.

I suggest that your benchmark is not realistic; don't allow that many simultaneous connections.

500% CPU means that all CPUs are busy all the time.  We need to look at the queries.  Come back when you have the slow log summary.